# Google Search Console 401 Bad Request issue without using Client Library

Tags: json, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-client, google-api-webmasters

So, Here are 3 steps.

I called oAuth2 with following url:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fwebmasters%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fwebmasters.readonly
&client_id=___.apps.googleusercontent.com
&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
&response_type=code
&approval_prompt=force
&access_type=offline
```

I get the code, suppose: `4/QVgPaCMqp94____qBC4NY_d54IcRj7U9mJc`

Then I'm making a request for access_token, by making a POST request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` with `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect_uri`, `grant_type`, and I get a JSON like:

```
'access_token' => ya29.CjHzAgC4js6Guv-1pt_rE____q8XIxiXOXOaSZW9NLRjKCTI3izBi,
'expires_in' => 3600,
'refresh_token' => 1/dL3ENA-EVI0rEb6D-OGqw_____iFe2ZNdEq4,
```

Now, I am making a request with that access_token or in cases of expiry with a renewed access_token to Google Search Console, which I have added in scopes.

My request is similar to this: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/urlcrawlerrorssamples/list#try-it

But I get an 401 unauthorized error, with a json like following:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Considering I have done the process correctly, I think I have missing some parameters or providing some wrong value.

I have not used Google Client Library, instead used the REST API framework directly.

Can anybody give some clue please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, URL query parameter must be `?access_token=` and not `?key=` The later can be used only in case of direct API access and not oAuth.